My Ledger Nano X Device Cannot Display "Blind Signing" When Asked By Phantom (Chrome) Wallet During Swapping of Tokens on DEXs
Dear Phantom Support,

My “new” (just bought) Ledger Nano X device (although has been updated to latest Firmware version 2.2.4) has failed to display “blind signing” when asked by my Phantom wallet (on Chrome browser) during swapping of coins/tokens on DEXs (Raydium & Jupiter). These incidents had happened despite I have clicked on to apply “blind signing” in the Ledger Nano X device.

However, this same “new” Ledger Nano X device, when used with another of my Phantom wallet (on Brave browser) worked well to display “blind signing” to successfully made the coins/tokens transactions. Therefore, the fault don’t seem to lie with the “new” Ledger Nano X device, but to the Phantom wallet itself, in my opinion. My Phantom wallet (Chrome) SOL address is 2un2cibpPzaE8My3vBJJhn9apsEEvBDMEkZ1Y7do2fMb

As a result of the failure faults of my Ledger Nano X Device, all my coins/tokens are now completely STUCKED/LOCKED-UP within my Phantom (Chrome) wallet & I could not trade/swap/send all the coins/tokens. This is GREATLY ADVERSELY IMPACTING my investments as the BULL RUN is already here!!!

Please advise what is happening to my Ledger Nano X Device, and the solutions to resolve all my problems herein.


Many Thanks!
Raymond

If you have a newer ledger X with bluetooth, you can use phantom mobile wallet to import your ledger wallet via a bluetooth connection and then make transactions using the mobile wallet for the time being. I was having issues myself when I was trying to claim an airdrop with my ledger on my computer, but was able to figure out how to make it work using the mobile wallet.
